# Drag-and-Drop API in Web Components (Lit)

Tags: javascript, html, events, drag-and-drop, web-component

### Background Context

I managed to learn the basics of the Drag-and-Drop API using normal elements and event listeners.  But I wanted to see if I could recreate the same functionality with Web Components.

After some trouble recreating my Drag-and-Drop functionality in a “vanilla” Web Component, I decided to give Lit a try (because it builds on existing standards, which I like).

### The Problem

Using a barebones setup to learn.

As simple as this is, the console is only firing `dragstart` events—but no `drag` or `dragend` events.

Here is the class:

```js
class LiDragdrop extends LitElement {

    static styles = css`
        :host   { display: block }
        :host b { display: inline-block }
    `

    constructor() {
        super()
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        super.connectedCallback()

        this.setAttribute('draggable', 'true')

        this.addEventListener('dragstart',  this.onDragStart, {passive: false})
        this.addEventListener('drag',       this.onDrag)
        this.addEventListener('dragend',    this.onDragEnd)
    }

    onDragStart(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault()
        evt.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move'
        evt.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', this.outerHTML)
        console.log(evt.type, `${evt.target.localName} (${evt.target.textContent})`, evt)
    }

    // fires repeatedly while dragging
    onDrag(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault()
        console.log(evt.type, `${evt.target.localName} (${evt.target.textContent})`, evt)
    }

    // always fires, even for unsuccessful drops
    onDragEnd(evt) {
        console.log(evt.type, evt.target.localName, evt)
    }

    render() {
        return html`<b>⠿</b><slot></slot>`
    }
}

customElements.define('li-dragdrop', LiDragdrop)
```

And besides the bare-bones HTML doc, here is all I have in the `body`:

```html
<li-dragdrop>Item 1</li-dragdrop>
<li-dragdrop>Item 2</li-dragdrop>
```

I drag the element. I see the `dragstart` logged to the console, but nothing else.

I am unsure if this is related to Shadow DOM events or Lit.

I just know that I was able to pull off using the complete API using standard HTML elements and some functions. As soon as I try with Web Components, I can’t get any further than `dragstart`.

Why?

Comment: A recent blog: https://www.redblobgames.com/making-of/draggable (not using the Drag/Drop API)

Answer (score 1):

All your Lit code does is create the shadowDOM for you.
That is 1 line in the ***native*** Web Component below.

Note: Doing Drag Drop yourself is a pain, will take you some days to get it working the way you want. Once you have done it for one application, you can do it in every application.

I don't do Lit. If this code doesn't work when extended from `LitElement`... then I have one more reason for not using Lit.

Biggest trip ups:

- Trying to handle too many events, that is why `dragover` below is limited to 1 second.
  Maybe use `dragenter` and `dragleave`
- `dataTransfer` IMHO is a pain.
  I usually store info about what is being dragged on a parentNode.. think `<chess-board>`
- Don't forget Event `touchmove` and all its cousins for touchscreens
- Too many DOM Nodes inside shadowDOM; below code has one... `<style>`
- Not using the System. Every JS Object can handle a default `handleEvent` function/method
- note how the cursor/grab position triggers the `dragover` event

```html
<div class="board">
  <drag-box color="red"></drag-box>
  <drag-box color="yellow"></drag-box>
  <drag-box color="blue"></drag-box>
</div>

<script>
  console.clear();
  customElements.define('drag-box', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super()
        .attachShadow({mode:'open'})
        .innerHTML = `<style>
                        :host {
                          display: inline-block;
                          width: 100px;
                          height: 100px;
                          cursor: grab;
                          background: var(--color)
                        }
                      </style>`;
      this.updatedragover = true;
    }
    connectedCallback() {
      this.color = this.color;
      this.setAttribute("draggable", true);
      // let JS default "handleEvent" on the class handle the event
      this.addEventListener('dragstart', this);
      this.addEventListener('dragend', this);
      this.addEventListener('dragover', this);
    }
    handleEvent(e) {
      if (this[e.type]) this[e.type](e); // exec method
    }
    dragover(e) {
      if (this.updatedragover) { // only once a second
        this.updatedragover = false;
        let dragcolor = this.board.dragging.color;
        console.log(dragcolor,'dragover', this.color);
        setTimeout(() => this.updatedragover = true, 1000);
      }
    }
    dragstart(e) {
      console.log(e.type, this.color);
      this.style.opacity = 0.3;
      this.board.dragging = this;
    }
    dragend(e) {
      console.log(e.type, this.color);
      this.style.opacity = 1;
    }
    get color() {
      return this.getAttribute("color") || "grey"
    }
    set color(c) {
      this.style.setProperty("--color", c);
    }
    get board(){
        return this.closest(".board");
    }
  })
</script>
```